# How do I group by the most recent date?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, subquery

I have a HISTORY table that has multiple rows for the same record and I am trying to get the latest (closest to today's date) record. I am attempting to group by the closest date but am having a difficult time. Please check out the query below and advise me.

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM
  (SELECT etc.Complaint.Complaint_ID AS Complaint_ID
     FROM etc.Complaint) AS Qry1  
     LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT etc.Complaint.Complaint_ID AS Complaint_ID,
                o.Action_User AS Resolved_User,
                o.Action_Date AS LastActionDate
           FROM etc.Complaint 
           LEFT OUTER JOIN etc.History as o 
             ON SUBSTRING(Primary_Key,15,LEN(Primary_Key) - 15) = etc.Complaint.Complaint_ID 
            AND TABLE_NAME = 'Resolution' AND o.Field_Name = 'Resolved_Ind' 
            AND New_Value = 1) AS Qry2 
       ON Qry1.Complaint_ID = Qry2.Complaint_ID
    ORDER BY Qry1.Complaint_ID, MAX(Qry2.LastActionDate)
```

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get?

Answer (score 0):

does this change help?

```
    SELECT DISTINCT *
    FROM
      (SELECT etc.Complaint.Complaint_ID AS Complaint_ID FROM etc.Complaint) AS Qry1  
         LEFT JOIN
            (SELECT etc.Complaint.Complaint_ID AS Complaint_ID,
                    o.Action_User AS Resolved_User,
                    o.Action_Date AS LastActionDate
               FROM etc.Complaint 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                  (
                        SELECT SUBSTRING(Primary_Key,15,LEN(Primary_Key) - 15) as hist_Complaint_ID , MAX(Action_Date) as Action_Date
                        FROM etc.History
                        WHERE Field_Name = 'Resolved_Ind' 
                        GROUP BY SUBSTRING(Primary_Key,15,LEN(Primary_Key) - 15)
                  ) as o
                 ON o.hist_Complaint_ID = etc.Complaint.Complaint_ID 
                AND TABLE_NAME = 'Resolution' AND o.Field_Name = 'Resolved_Ind' 
                AND New_Value = 1) AS Qry2 
           ON Qry1.Complaint_ID = Qry2.Complaint_ID
        ORDER BY Qry1.Complaint_ID, Qry2.LastActionDate
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` and a CTE to get it:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT etc.Complaint.Complaint_ID AS Complaint_ID,
                    o.Action_User AS Resolved_User,
                    o.Action_Date AS LastActionDate
                    row_number() over (partition by etc.Complaint.Complaint_ID order by o.Action_Date desc) AS rn
    FROM etc.Complaint 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN etc.History as o 
        ON SUBSTRING(Primary_Key,15,LEN(Primary_Key) - 15) = etc.Complaint.Complaint_ID 
    AND TABLE_NAME = 'Resolution' AND o.Field_Name = 'Resolved_Ind' 
    AND New_Value = 1
)

SELECT * FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```